# Contar cuántos ceros hay en una lista de n números enteros

Tags: python

```
lista2 = [1, 10, 20, 4, 3, 50, 0]
cont = 0
for i in lista2:
    if 0 in lista2:
        cont +=1
print(f"Hay, {cont}")
```

Comment: Buen día, no es claro lo que deseas hacer, si contar los dígitos que sean igual a cero o contar los enteros que sean igual a cero. Es decir, si cuentas los dígitos que sean igual a cero el resultado sería 4, pero si cuentas los enteros que sean cero el resultado sería 1. Por favor repasa la sección [ask] y agrega un ejemplo del resultado deseado.

Comment: no es muy clara la pregunta ni lo que esperas obtener, suponiendo que quieres saber cuantos 0 hay en total por cada elemento de la lista deberías cambiar a  if "0" in str(i):  la línea  if 0 in lista2:

Comment: Pon el resultado esperado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo un poco tu lógica de programa te muestro tres ejemplos:

1. Calculando ocurrencias de números ceros en una lista

   ```
    lista2 = [1, 10, 20, 4, 3, 50, 0,100]
    cont = 0
    for i in lista2:
        if 0 in [i]:
            cont +=1
    print(f"Hay, {cont}")

    Hay, 1
   ```
2. Cómo contar la ocurrencia de un carácter 0 en una lista de cadena o
   números

   ```
     lista2 = [1, 10, 20, 4, 3, 50, 0,100]
     cont = 0
     for i in lista2:
         if '0' in (set(str(i))):
             cont +=1
     print(f"Hay, {cont}")

     Hay, 5
   ```
3. Cómo contar la ocurrencia de un carácter 0 en una lista de cadena o
   números con repetición

   ```
    lista2 = [1, 10, 20, 4, 3, 50, 0,100]
    cont = 0
    for i in lista2:
        if '0' in (str(i)):
            cont +=str(i).count('0')
    print(f"Hay, {cont}")

    Hay, 6
   ```

Lo mismo pero mas compacto

```
    print(str(lista2).count('0'))
```

Comment: god grcs amigo... la numero 3 es la solucion a mi problema . GRACIAS

Answer (score 4):

Solución pythonica usando comprensión de listas

```
print(len([x for x in lista2 if x == 0]))
```

Explicación:

`x for x in lista2` es una forma compacta de tomar los elementos de `lista2` uno por uno.

`if x == 0` significa que cada elemento se examina y si cumple la condición, se agrega a la lista de salida. El resultado es una lista con los ceros encontrados.

La expresión completa

```
[x for x in lista2 if x == 0]
```

produce una lista con los ceros encontrados.

Con `len()` obtenemos el largo de la lista, que es lo mismo que el número de ceros.

Answer (score 2):

A ver te puedo aclarar.
prueba y mira ver si funciona.

```
def detectarNUM(num,lista):
    cont=0
    for i in lista:
        if i == num:
            cont+=1
    return cont
```

la variable `(num)` sirve para saber que numero quieres ver en la lista.
la variable `(lista)` es para que pongas la lista a registrar.
Ya con esto dicho creas la lista.

```
l=[12,0,13,15,16,0,0,0,12]
```

ahora llamas a la funcion `detectarNUM()` de varias maneras.

```
a=detectarNUM(0,l)
b=detectarNUM(12,l)
print("hay"+str(a)+"ceros en la lista.")
print("hay"+str(b)+"doces en la lista.")
```

resultado:

```
hay 4 ceros en la lista.
hay 2 doces en la lista.
```

si te fue util valora la respuesta :)